# How to get all combinations of "sub" lists from a list

Tags: python

So if I start with something like:

```
x = [a, b, c]
y = [[a], [b], [c], [a,b], [b,c]]
```

How can I get all of the combinations in which I can make `x` from elements in `y`? Something like:

```
y = [ [[a, b], c], [[b,c], a], [a, b, c]
```

I have looked into itertools and list comprehension, but still struggling. 
All elements from original list need to be present in each item of resulting list.

Comment: Could you describe your expected result a little more fully/generally? At the moment it looks like you're trying to get something halfway between the partitions  and the power set.

Comment: To follow on @PatrickHaugh I'm surprised you don't have `[a, b], [b, c], [a, c]` too

Comment: What would the output be if there are more than three elements? Would you create multiple sublists? i.e `x = [a, b, c, d]; [[[a, b], [c, d]], [[a, b, c], d]]`?

Comment: Something like this for the output of 4 elements:
`[ [a,b,c,d], [[a,b],c,d], [a,[b,c],d], [a,b,[c,d]], [[a,c],b,d]], [[a,d],b,c]], ... [[a,b,c],d], [a,[b,c,d]], [b,[a,c,d]]...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now assuming you have a list of valid combinations that can be used. Using a recursive function I was able to get the desired output.

Note: I have done 0 optimization

```
import numpy


def build_combo(current_set, all_combos):
    global count, req_options
    for each in all_combos:
        if all(len(numpy.intersect1d(each, x)) == 0 for x in current_set):
            inner_set = current_set.copy()
            inner_set.append(each)
            flat = []
            for x in inner_set:
                flat.extend(x)
            if all(x in flat for x in req_options):
                built_combos.append(inner_set)
            else:
                build_combo(inner_set, all_combos)


req_options = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

all_combos = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'], ['g'],
              ['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['a', 'f'], ['f', 'g'],
              ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['g', 'f', 'e', 'b']]

built_combos = []
build_combo([], all_combos)

option_sets = set()
for combo in built_combos:
    newset = set()
    for element in combo:
        newset.add(frozenset(element))
    option_sets.add(frozenset(newset))

for option_set in option_sets:
    combo_str = ''
    for option in option_set:
        combo_str += '[{}]'.format('+'.join(option))
    print(combo_str)
```

Output (added '+' signs to printed output for easier reading):

```
[e][g][c+d][b][f+a]
[a][c][d][f+e+g+b]
[f+g][e][c][d][a+b]
[f+g][e][c+d][a][b]
[f][e][c][g][a][b][d]
[c+a+d][f][e][g][b]
[b][e][f+g][c+a+d]
[f][e][g][c+d][a+b]
[f+g][e][a+b][c+d]
[f][e][g][c+d][a][b]
[e][c][g][b][f+a][d]
[f+g][e][c][a][b][d]
[f][e][c][g][d][a+b]
[a][f+e+g+b][c+d]
[c+a+d][f+e+g+b]
```

Answer (score 0):

How to get a combination for every item in a list?

Loop over the list, and loop over the list again inside that loop:

```
x = [a, b, c]
y = []
for i in x:
    for j in x:
        y.append([i, j])
```

Note that the exact output you asked for is not "a combination for every item in a list" - in fact there does not seem to be consistency in your exact output which means neither this nor anything from a standard library is going to help you, but this should give you a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function with a generator:

```
def full_length(d):
  return sum(1 if not isinstance(i, list) else full_length(i) for i in d)

def semi_combos(d, current=[]):
   if len(current) == len(x) - 1:
     yield current
   else:
     for i in d:
       if len(set(current+[i])) == len(current)+1:
         yield from semi_combos(d, current+[i])

def remainder_combos(d, _target, current = []):
  if full_length(current)+len(_target) == len(x):
    yield [_target, *current]
  for i in d:
    if i not in _target and i not in current:
      yield from remainder_combos(d, _target, current+[i])


for x in [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]:
  print([b for i in semi_combos(x) for b in list(remainder_combos(x, i))])
```

Output:

```
[[['a', 'b'], 'c'], [['a', 'c'], 'b'], [['b', 'a'], 'c'], [['b', 'c'], 'a'], [['c', 'a'], 'b'], [['c', 'b'], 'a']]
```

---

```
[[['a', 'b', 'c'], 'd'], [['a', 'b', 'd'], 'c'], [['a', 'c', 'b'], 'd'], [['a', 'c', 'd'], 'b'], [['a', 'd', 'b'], 'c'], [['a', 'd', 'c'], 'b'], [['b', 'a', 'c'], 'd'], [['b', 'a', 'd'], 'c'], [['b', 'c', 'a'], 'd'], [['b', 'c', 'd'], 'a'], [['b', 'd', 'a'], 'c'], [['b', 'd', 'c'], 'a'], [['c', 'a', 'b'], 'd'], [['c', 'a', 'd'], 'b'], [['c', 'b', 'a'], 'd'], [['c', 'b', 'd'], 'a'], [['c', 'd', 'a'], 'b'], [['c', 'd', 'b'], 'a'], [['d', 'a', 'b'], 'c'], [['d', 'a', 'c'], 'b'], [['d', 'b', 'a'], 'c'], [['d', 'b', 'c'], 'a'], [['d', 'c', 'a'], 'b'], [['d', 'c', 'b'], 'a']]
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like either of your outputs match?